# Выборка данных из БД

Tags: php, mysql

Есть массив. Требуется выбрать из БД все строки, где значение указанной колонки будет равно одному из элементов массива.

Суть вопроса в том, как сделать это **правильно**, коротко и быстро. Заниматься изобретением умеют все, но требуется грамотный подход.

пример:

```
$arr = array(0=>1, 1=>2, 2=>4 /* ... n=>m */)
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT title,value FROM $someTable WHERE id='любому из элемента масива $arr'");
while ($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
//do something
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно делают так (распишу в отдельных строках, чтоб было нагляднее):

```
$sql = mysql_query(
    "SELECT title, value FROM $someTable WHERE id IN (" . 
    join(',', $array) . 
    ")"
);
```

Вполне работает, пока по длине запроса в `max_allowed_packet` не упретесь.

И да — это *почти* правильно, коротко и быстро :)
Чтобы было совсем правильно, элементы массива (в зависимости от типа) следует квотить/эскейпить. В php это делает, кажется, функция `mysql_escape_string()`

Comment: Благодарю